# detecting type of file (regular file, directory, symbolic link, etc)

Tags: c

I'm trying to use [stat(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to determine whether argv[i] is a regular file, directory, or symbolic link. There are 2 things that I don't understand from the `stat(2)` man page:

1. What is the second argument that `stat(2)` takes (i.e. the buf arg)

   ```
    int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
   ```
2. How do I use the return value to determine whether it's a reg file, dir, or sym link?

Comment: The page says what "the return value" is for. As usual, it is to indicate success or failure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the first question, you can dereference an instance of a `stat` struct and pass that dereferenced value to `stat()` to populate the instance's field values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* ... */

struct stat foo;
const char *path = "/a/b/c";

/* test the result of stat() to make sure it ran correctly */

if (stat(path, &foo) != 0) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "something went wrong with stat()\n"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}

/* now do stuff with foo; e.g. from docs: */

switch (foo.st_mode & S_IFMT) {
    case S_IFBLK:  printf("block device\n");            break;
    case S_IFCHR:  printf("character device\n");        break;
    case S_IFDIR:  printf("directory\n");               break;
    case S_IFIFO:  printf("FIFO/pipe\n");               break;
    case S_IFLNK:  printf("symlink\n");                 break;
    case S_IFREG:  printf("regular file\n");            break;
    case S_IFSOCK: printf("socket\n");                  break;
    default:       printf("unknown?\n");                break;
}
```

To answer the second question, from the documentation you linked to:

```
The following POSIX macros are defined to check 
the file type using the st_mode field:

S_ISREG(m) - is it a regular file?
S_ISDIR(m) - directory?
S_ISCHR(m) - character device?
S_ISBLK(m) - block device?
S_ISFIFO(m) - FIFO (named pipe)?
S_ISLNK(m) - symbolic link? (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)
S_ISSOCK(m) - socket? (Not in POSIX.1-1996.)
```

The `st_mode` field gets populated if `stat()` is successful, so you can pass that result to the macros listed above:

```
if (S_ISREG(foo.st_mode)) { 
    fprintf(stderr, "whatever foo points to is a regular file\n"); 
}
else {
    fprintf(stderr, "whatever foo points to is something else\n"); 
}
```

You should first test the result of `stat()` to ensure that you have usable values in `st_mode` and other fields. Again, refer to the documention, which is actually very well-written, or see the code snippet above.

Comment: but how would I use these macros given some filename argv[i]? Thanks

Comment: Given the documentation, again: `if (S_ISREG(foo.st_mode)) { /* blah */ }`

Comment: @Apollo: the macros do not accept a filename, they must be used with the `struct st` member `st_mode`. See that page you linked to for an example.